# Wrong tag content when using Maven release:perform

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that creates a release of a maven based project from a branch. My problem is that the contents of the resulting tag in /tags is the full content of /branches and not the single branch I was expecting.

The project uses a normal subversion setup (trunk/branches/tags). The SCM setup in the pom file looks like this:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://myproduct/branches</developerConnection>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://myproduct/branches</connection>
</scm>
```

The content of /branches:

[image]

I want to create releases from the 1.x branch. I use release:perform to create the release and I have set up 4 parameters in the Jenkins job.

[image]

These parameters are transfered to maven during the build process:

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
channel stopped
[workspace] $ mvn -Ddevelopment_version=1.3.0-SNAPSHOT -Dtag_name=1.2.1 -Drelease_version=1.2.1 -Dbranch_name=1.x release:perform
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

I was expecting maven to add the value of the branch_name to the SCM connection value like so:

```
scm:svn:https://myproduct/branches/1.x
```

to select the correct branch. But this doesn't happen. It uses "//myproduct/branches" and this results in the following tag (in /tags):

[image]

I was expecting only to find the contents of branches/1.x in the tag.

Is this what the "branch_name" parameter is for? If not is there another way to achieve it?

Comment: When you created you Job what did you put in "Repository URL" ?

Comment: @NAIT In "Repository URL" I have "//myproduct/branches/${branch_name}".